# Is there a way to mirror data changes between source and destination google sheets when using copyFormResponses function after a form submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

TheWizEd, followed up by, [Fernando Lara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17926591/fernando-lara)  answered a question regarding duplicating Google Form submissions using the following code for an AppScript:

```
function copyFormResponses(e) {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Insert Spreadsheet URL here").getSheetByName("Insert the Sheet name here");
  let range = e.range;
  let values = e.values;
  let lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  for(let i=1; i<=values.length; i++)
  {
      ss.getRange(lastRow+1, i).setValue(values[i-1]);
  }
}
```

This works brilliantly!  My follow up question is:  Is there a way to make it so a change to the data in the source Sheet after a form submission has been made will be reflected in the destination sheet?

Thanks!

I tried adding a trigger to the AppScript for either "on edit" or "on change" but neither produced a successful result.

Comment: onEdit triggers only fire on user edits

Comment: The form does not change values in the linked sheet it just adds rows so any form submission will be captured  by the onFormSubmit trigger and you can copy it to whatever destination you wish

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation:

Here's two script on how to copy data from source to destination sheet using form submission depends on your need.

### Script 1:

Copy data from source to destination every new submission from the form is added.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order");
    var data = source.getRange(1, 1, source.getLastRow(), 10).getValues();
    var row = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
        destinationSheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
        destinationSheet.getRange(1, 1, source.getLastRow(), 10).setValues(data);  
}
```

Set a trigger with the event type on Form Submit.
[image: onFormsubmit]

### Script 2:

Copy data from source to destination sheet whenever there is manual edit from the source sheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Order");
  if (e.value !== "") {
        var data = source.getRange(1, 1, source.getLastRow(), 10).getValues();
        var row = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
        destinationSheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
        destinationSheet.getRange(1, 1, source.getLastRow(), 10).setValues(data);  
  }
```

}

Set a trigger with the event type on Edit.
[image: onEdit]

**Note:** clearContent() is added on both codes to avoid duplicate entries.

### References:

- [OnFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question, or if there are some clarifications needed so that I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to remove the time stamp and send the values to another sheet

```
function copyFormResponses(e) {
  let sh = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Insert Spreadsheet URL here").getSheetByName("Insert the Sheet name here");
  let values = e.values.slice();
  values.shift();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,values.length).setValues([values])
}
```